# Opportunity Quick Action is unable to display Opportnity Line Items using Screen Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, opportunity, opportunity-lineitem, screen-flow

I have an issue where I create a screen flow for the Opportunity object that would create one of 3 types  Refund records base on a button click: a) Direct, b) Credit, and c) Duplicate.

- Direct Refund button click causes a Data Table to display the list of Opportunity items to select.
- Credit Refund button click also causes a  Data Table to display the list of Opportunity items to select .

[image]

> I then created the Quick Action for the Opportunity Object.
> [image]
> [image]
>
> However when I try clicking on the Quick Action button (Request Refund) , the opportunity Line Items don't appear in the data table for the screen flow as they did when testing the flow in Flow Builder Debug.
> [image]

> Here is the Data Table for the Screen flow. Just wondering if there is some permissions issue with displaying Line Items or something else. Thanks:
> [image]

Comment: does your screen flow do a get records on the Opportunity (or OLIs) given the recordID passed from the quick action?

Comment: Nope. Maybe that might do it but I have to investigate because the record ID was not passed from the quick action like a Detail Button would do when calling a flow in its formula canvas.

Comment: see this [blog post](https://salesforcetime.com/2021/10/20/using-an-action-to-pass-the-entire-record-to-a-flow/#:~:text=However%2C%20actions%20know%20to%20pass,to%20map%20the%20values%20manually.)

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks to @cropredy who gave me a hint:  I did have the recordId text variable as part of the flow **however** I misspelled the name as "*recordID*" and not "*recordId*" (All other properties were correct). As soon as I changed the name, everything worked and I was able to click on the Direct Refund button to verify that the screen flow data table displayed the OLIs (Order Line Items/ Opp Products) and that these OLIs were selectable.  Thanks much.

Comment: ah yes -- Flow input and output variables are case sensitive